# Pass a Boolean to a function or call one of two separate functions

Tags: javascript, beginner

Is it better performance or not to call one of two separate functions in response to an `if` statement over passing an argument to a function? And, what are the performance implications?

My first function checks for the existence of a cookie:

```
function checkCookie() {

    var accept=getCookie("_cmci");
    if (accept !== "") {
        trueshow(); //or display(true)
    } else {
        falseShow(); //or display (false)               
    }
}
```

should I call trueShow / falseShow over display(true) / display(false) for better performance? Is it necessary to be concerned about an additional variable bound when entering a scope at runtime?

```
function display(showObject) {
if ( showObject === true ) {
  console.log("it be visible"); //display notification
} else {
  console.log("it be invisible"); //display notification
}
updateView();
}
```

Or

```
function trueShow() {
  console.log("it be visible"); //display notification
  updateView();
}
function falseShow() {
  console.log("it be invisible"); //display notification
  updateView();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please see [why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243) for the reason behind my vote to, unfortunately, close this question.

Comment: The two code samples being compared are not equivalent. There is no conditional in `trueShow()` / `falseShow()`. Also, the two functions do the "same" thing except for the difference in the logged message, so it makes little sense.

Comment: While the edit makes the question better, it is still hypothetical.  The functions don't do anything other than log messages and call `updateView()`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Although I wouldn't quite say it was hypothetical as updateView() just displays a string and adjusts the css values of two elements in response. I can add the function  but it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Don't over optimize.

Comment: I believe you may be right @Pinoniq, given this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/two-or-one-function) test, there would seem to be negligible difference...

Comment: First make it work, then fix it. If you then have time, fix the slowest part of you code. And trust me, that will never be calling a function in different ways. This is the job of the compilers/interpreters/... And they are written by people who are a lot smarter then us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first of the two is more efficient because, in the second one, you are jumping all around the place which is lightly inefficient, but it can also reduce readability.

Also, in the functions version, since the functions are only two lines, it's sort of a waste of time.

Now in regards to improving your code...

- Your formatting is a little off. I'm not sure if this is just your editor, but indents are generally 4 spaces, while yours are only 3. Also, there are some places that aren't indented at all
- In your `if` statement, you don't need to have `=== true`; an `if` statement automatically checks if the statement is `true`.
- Some people don't like this, as it is confusing at times, but if an `if` statement only does one thing after the conditional check, you can omit the `{` and `}`
- Instead of having two different `console.log`s, you can store one string with "it be " and then append "visible" or "invisible" before you log the string.

With those improvements added, your code will look something like:

```
function display(showObject) {
    var string = "it be "; // the default string

    if(showObject) {
        string += "visible"; // append visible
    } else {
        string += "invisible"; // append invisible
    }

    console.log(string);
    updateView();
}
```